# Does MongoDB use indexes for "joined" collections?

Tags: mongodb

I have two collections: a and b. b has field x. 
There is index for field x in collection b.

When I'm trying :

```
    db.a.aggregate([
            $lookup:{
                from:"b",
                localField:"parent.id",
                foreignField:"_id",
                as:"joined"
                }
            },
            {
                '$match':{
                    'joined.x':{'$gt':2}
                }
            }
])
```

It does not use index. What's wrong?

UPDATE.

It does not index even in such way:

```
db.a.aggregate([{$lookup: {
                from: "b",
                let: { parentId: "$parent.id"},
                pipeline: [
                    { $match:
                        { $expr:
                            { $eq: [ "$x",  2 ] },
                            { $eq: [ "$_id",  $$parentId ] },
                        }
                    }
                ],
                as: "joined"
            }}
            ])
```

Comment: `$match` can only take the advantage of  indexing if it is used as the first stage in the aggregation pipeline.

Comment: `$lookup` is creating a new document, on which you're then matching. It doesn't really have any semblance to the documents in either `contents` or `b`.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing wrong with `mongodb` or your query here.

The only stage that can use an index in an aggregation pipeline is the first stage only, and that must be either `$match` or `$geoNear` or `$sort.

From MongoDB version 3.2 it can cover the entire pipeline, but only `$match` or `$geoNear` or `$sort`, but since, $lookup creates entirely new document, so mongodb pipeline is not able to use the indices in the next `$match` stage.

Read [Aggregation pipeline behaviour](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/aggregation-pipeline/#aggregation-pipeline-operators-and-performance) for more information.

Comment: Changed in version 3.2: Starting in MongoDB 3.2, indexes can cover an aggregation pipeline.

Comment: I've updated my question, could you please take a look?